# How to create multi dimensional array in php without specifying index

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I am newbie programmer of php. How should I create array without specifying the size of array.I have tried using

```
$items = array();
```

How can add array as the element? Without having to specify the index. Thanks in advance for any feedback.

Comment: $items[] = '1', $items[] = '2' ... But this is not multidimensional. Is only one dimension :)

Comment: can you show some code that you have written already ?

Comment: what are the specific application needs for which you need multi-dimensional array ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// define array

$item = array();

// adding multi dimensional array

array_push($item, array('name'=>'Pen','qty'=>1));
```

You may nest the array to even more levels by same method as mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

creating mutlidimesional array in php is easy stuff

```
<?php 
$shop = array( array("rose", 1.25 , 15),
               array("daisy", 0.75 , 25),
               array("orchid", 1.15 , 7) 
             ); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

$items[] = 'my new item';

check [the php manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)